# Fatal Error DISPLAY variable set incorrectly: :0

Tags: weblogic, oracle-fusion-middleware

I want to install oracle weblogic server. I already downloaded it and it's `fmw_12.1.3.0.0_wls.jar`. In order to install it I'm instructed to run `java -jar fmw_12.1.3.0.0_wls.jar`. But when I run it I get

```
(...)X-Server access is denied on host
[Fatal Error] DISPLAY variable set incorrectly: :0
[Resolution] Verify that your DISPLAY environment variable is set correctly, 
and that there is an X11 server on the system. If you are 
running the Oracle Installer as a different user or on a different host, 
you may need to use the xhost command to ensure that host/user 
has permission to write to your display.

Logs are located here: /tmp/OraInstall2019-03-16_10-36-23PM.
```

My system is: CentOS Linux release 7.6.1810 (Core) My java is: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_80-b15)

I'm trying to perform this installation locally. I'm confused because every solution I came across assumed that I was logging via ssh or vnc server while I'm definitely not. What I tried:

- set $JAVA_HOME to point to my jdk directory.
- unset $ORACLE_HOME that was created for the database I have installed.
- trying to set DISPLAY    values to some other number than 0 (I know
  its stupid but whatever).
- reinstall java

I'm thinking if it might be the problem related with graphic drivers. Might it be that the defaults that were installed with X11 are somehow wrong? Or maybe centOS is not compatibile with this software? Should I maybe try oracle linux?

Answer (score 1):

Add `-Djava.awt.headless=true` to your command line, e.g.

```
java -Djava.awt.headless=true -jar fmw_12.1.3.0.0_wls.jar
```

Comment: Thanks for trying to help but I got same error message as before.

Answer (score 1):

I solved my problem by using jdk 1.8 x64. This issue seemed to be caused by jdk 1.8 x86.
And yes, the problem was similar to yours. Give it a shot.